# jQuery doesn't work in partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have a problem with partial view in MVC3 Razor. When I normally render partial view (with Html.RenderAction) jQuery works but when I load view, in a specific div, with ajax.actionlink jQuery for that partial view doesn't work.
jQuery code is in my layout page.

Anyone knows what is the problem?

html is in partial view and script is in layout page.

when i load partial view with `@{Html.RenderAction("action", "Controler"); }` jquery works but when i load it with:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("name", "action", "controler", new AjaxOptions
                  {

                      OnComplete = "",
                      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                      UpdateTargetId = "ModeliSadrzaj"
                  })
```

it dosent work

Comment: check the browser console for error. Probably not loading the jquery.js properly.

Comment: We will be able to help you better if you provide us some code samples, or et least a little more detail of what is being done where.

Comment: can you share a sample of code so that I can understand your problem and would help you in a better way ?

Comment: In your browser click on the view source to check either the jquery file is linked or not

Comment: script is in head of layout and is working just fine when a partial view is load with Html.RenderAction. I check and there is no errors in browser consol

Answer (score 2):

I would need more information on what exactly is being done where, but I suspect that the following is the source of your problem.

When you use Html.RenderAction, your partial view is a part of the initial package sent to the browser. Then your javascript code (in the Layout page) is able to work on it upon document.ready event. Things work as they should.

When you use Ajax.ActionLink, your page only has an  tag on it, which when clicked will load your partial view. Have you set up the code in your layout page to run **only after the ActionLink has completed**? If your layout page code runs on document ready, then the partial view is not there yet (since its only loaded after you click the link).

The ActionLink action does not automatically load your content, is what I am trying to say. So its not really comparable to the Html.RenderAction function.

Comment: ok i found solution...in

@Ajax.ActionLink("name", "action", "controler", new AjaxOptions
                  {
                      HttpMethod="POST",
                      OnComplete = "",
                      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                      UpdateTargetId = "ModeliSadrzaj"
                  })

thx anyway :)